# Issue With Translating SQL Item to String

Tags: c#, sql, string

I have searched the internet for an answer to my current question, but have found nothing. I have an SQL database that I am trying to get an item from as a string. My database is as follows:
[image: Database Table]
[image: Table Data]

Now, I try to get a 95Number in the following code:

```
connection.Open();
readerUsers = commandUsers.ExecuteReader();
while (readerUsers.Read())
           ...
                IDNumber = readerUsers[2].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(IDNumber);
```

Unfortunately, every `MessageBox.Show(IDNumber);` that I call only returns `"95"`. I have also tried `IDNumber = readerUsers["95Number"].ToString();`, as was recommended online, and that only brought about a fatal error. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for your time, and have a great day!

EDIT: 
The query for `commandUsers` is as follows:

```
stringUsers = "SELECT IDuser, Username, 95Number, Password, Active, Admin, Teacher FROM dbo.Users;";
commandUsers = new SqlCommand(stringUsers, connection);
```

Comment: Could you include the SQL query.

Comment: @Simon please update your question with SQL query used.

Comment: @juharr My apologies, I am quite a noob with SQL. What is the query again? Is that the connection string?

Comment: No it's the text string you assign to `commandUsers.CommandText`

Comment: @juharr Ah, my apologies. I just edited the post to show that. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SELECT 95Number` the `95` will be recognized as a value instead of column name.
It's not considered a good practice that using number at the beginning of column name, perhaps you can change the name to `Number95`?

If you really want to keep the column name as the way it is. Put the column name in square brackets will make the query works as your expectation.

```
SELECT [95Number] FROM Users
```

Comment: This also explains why `readerUsers["95Number"]` didn't work as it's created a column named "Number" with the value 95